# Handling a service call inside another service call in pact tests for angular (run with jest)

Tags: angular, asynchronous, pact

In an angular 9 project I have a service which calls an endpoint (call it endpoint_A) which starts a task running on the server and returns a task ID string as well as a header with a URL to check the task status while it runs (call this endpoint_B).  The angular service looks like this

```
import {Inject, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Rule} from '../model/rule';
import {Observable, Subscriber} from 'rxjs';
import {UniqueHeaders} from '../model/unique-headers';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RuleService {
  constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

  getRules(): Observable<Rule[]> {
    return new Observable<Rule[]>((subscriber => {
      this.httpClient.get<Rule[]>('endpoint_A', {observe: 'response'})
        .subscribe((response) => {
          this.checkResponse(response, subscriber);
        });
    }));
  }

  private checkResponse(httpResp: HttpResponse<any>, subscriber: Subscriber<any>, lastDelay?: number): void {
    if (httpResp.status === 200) {
      // The task has completed, see if we need to make another call to get the result
      const retrievalUrl: string = httpResp.headers.get(UniqueHeaders.LOCATION);
      if (location) {
        // Make the call and return the result to the observer
        this.httpClient.get<any>(retrievalUrl).subscribe(
          (resp: any) => subscriber.next(resp)
        );
      } else {
        // Just return the result
        subscriber.next(httpResp.body);
      }
      return;
    }

    if (httpResp.status === 202 || httpResp.status === 204) {
      // We will initially get a 202 for Accepted and then 204s as we poll to check the progress.  Notify
      // the observer we're making another call and then do it after waiting a bit.
      subscriber.next(null);

      // See if the server is telling us how long to delay before calling back
      let delay = Number(httpResp.headers.get(UniqueHeaders.DELAY));
      console.log(UniqueHeaders.DELAY + ' : ' + delay);
      if (isNaN(delay) || delay < 1) {
        // If there wasn't a header or the value is not valid, use either the last known delay or a default of 1 second
        delay = (lastDelay) ? lastDelay : 1000;
      }
      const retrievalUrl: string = httpResp.headers.get(UniqueHeaders.LOCATION);
      console.log(UniqueHeaders.LOCATION + ' : ' + retrievalUrl);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.httpClient.get<any>(retrievalUrl, {observe: 'response'}).subscribe(
          (nextHttpResp: HttpResponse<any>) => this.checkResponse(nextHttpResp, subscriber, delay)
        );
      }, delay);
    }
  }
}
```

The service works fine, however when I attempt to add a pact test for this service

```
import {TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {InteractionObject } from '@pact-foundation/pact-web';
import {PactUtils} from './pact-utils';
import {RuleService} from './rule-service.service';
import {Rule} from '../model/rule';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Pact} from '@pact-foundation/pact';

const provider: Pact = PactUtils.getProvider('rule-service', 'my-provider');

const mockRule: Rule = {
  index: 0,
  name: 'mock Rule'
};
const getIdInteraction: InteractionObject = PactUtils.getTaskStatusStartInteraction('/endpoint_A',
  '/endpoint_B/' + PactUtils.MOCK_TASK_ID);
const getResultInteraction: InteractionObject =
  PactUtils.getTaskStatusCompletedInteraction('/endpoint_B/' + PactUtils.MOCK_TASK_ID, mockRule);

// Setup Pact mock server for this service
beforeAll(async () => {
  await provider.setup();
});

// Verify mock service
afterEach(async () => {
  await provider.verify();
});

// Create contract
afterAll(async () => {
  await provider.finalize();
});

// Configure Angular Testbed for this service
beforeEach(async () => {
  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      HttpClientModule
    ],
    providers: [
      RuleService
    ]
  });
});

describe('RuleService::getRules()', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await provider.addInteraction(getIdInteraction);
    await provider.addInteraction(getResultInteraction);
  });

  it('should get all rules', async (done) => {
    const ruleService: RuleService = TestBed.inject(RuleService);
    ruleService.getRules().subscribe((response) => {
      expect(response).toEqual([mockRule]);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

I get an error

```
console.error
    Error: Uncaught HttpErrorResponse {
      headers: HttpHeaders {
        normalizedNames: Map {},
        lazyUpdate: null,
        lazyInit: [Function]
      },
      status: 202,
      statusText: 'Accepted ',
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/endpoint_A',
      ok: false,
      name: 'HttpErrorResponse',
      message: 'Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/endpoint_A',
      error: {
        error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token f in JSON at position 1
            at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
            ...
            at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21),
        text: '9f32d86d-e62a-4cf7-a60a-f9311a57c8ca'
      }
    }
```

It seems like because the angular service is expecting a json object to be returned that it causes a failure in the pact test when the first endpoint is hit and returns a string.

Has anybody had to deal with nested calls like this with pact tests in angular?  And if so how do you get around this?

I've created a minimal example on my github (https://github.com/mdwerner/minimal-example) for those who want to try it out.  The failure happens when running the 'test:pact' script in package.json.

Comment: *"the angular service is expecting a json object to be returned that it causes a failure in the pact test when the first endpoint is hit and returns a string"* - then *shouldn't* the test fail? Either the contract is wrong or the implementation is.